# basic second order system transfer function - natural period and natural frequency

Tags: control-engineering

I have a question about general second-order system transfer functions. I notice two takes on this transfer function. One has a denominator of:

$$\tau^2 s^2 + 2\zeta\tau s + 1$$

where $\tau$ (tau) as they defined it - is 'natural period of oscillations' (not time constant), which is seen (for example) in the formula at this link [here](https://www.et.byu.edu/~tom/classes/436/ClassNotes/Class20(Second-Order).pdf).

And then there is another transfer function (seen in other control engineering textbooks) with a denominator of:

$$s^2 + 2\zeta w_n s + w_n^2$$

Now, if I divide the first expression by $\tau^2$, I get:

$$s^2 + 2\frac{\zeta}{\tau}s + \frac{1}{\tau^2}$$

So I can now compare $s^2 + 2\zeta w_n s + w_n^2$ and $s^2 + 2\frac{\zeta}{\tau}s + \frac{1}{\tau^2}$.

Equating the constants of those two expressions above, I get:

$$w_n^2 = \frac{1}{\tau^2}$$

which boils down to $w_n = \dfrac{1}{\tau}$ or

$$\tau = \frac {1}{w_n}$$

Now, the natural period of oscillations $\tau$ is supposed to have units of time (eg. seconds). And angular frequency $w_n$ is supposed to have units of radian per second.

The actual mathematical relation between angular frequency and period is supposed to be $w_n = 2\pi \frac{1}{\tau}$, where $1/\tau$ is $f_n$ (the cyclic frequency in Hz).

The comparison of the two second order transfer functions leads to $\tau = \frac{1}{w_n}$. But formally - the relation between $\tau$ and $w_n$ should actually be $\tau = 2\frac{\pi}{w_n}$.

That is $\tau = \frac {1}{w_n}$ versus $\tau = \frac{2\pi}{w_n}$.

The question is - why is the above mathematical conflict occurring? A factor of $2\pi$ out.

I'm definitely missing something here. But would definitely like to understand the missing link.

Could it be that the $\tau$ seen in $\tau^2 s^2 + 2\zeta\tau s + 1$ has been incorrectly defined as the natural period of oscillations?

Comment: I guess this is just careless terminology. The standard equations always use radians. After all, in real life people measure frequencies in RPM as well as Hz, but the underlying equations always give *angular* frequencies in rad/sec.

Comment: alephzero - could it be a case that their 'tau' is not really period of natural oscillations? Instead their 'tau' is probably (natural period of oscillations)/(2.pi), ie. T/(2.pi). That is, their tau is : tau = T/(2.pi), where 'T' is the actual natural period of oscillations.